# Angular2 which has a WinJS component which has another Angular2 component not working

Tags: angularjs, winjs

As you notice in the following code, the **dashboard.cshtml** has an *angular2* component called **dashboard-app**. The **dashboard-app** has a *winjs* splitter control that comes from **dashboard.html**. This control has another **contentara** *angular2* component.

When I run the following, I don't see any errors in the console. But I don't see the **contentarea** rendered.

My expectation is to see *Testing* in the content area. I assume *bootstrap(MyAppComponent);* (from **app.js**) should wire-up the whole app, so I should see *Testing* in the content area which comes from the **contentarea** component.

**Output from Chrome:**

[image]

**Dashboard.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <dashboard-app></dashboard-app>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="/jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
<script src="/config.js"></script>

<script>
    System.import('reflect-metadata')
        .then(function () {
            System.import('angular2')
                .then(function () {
                    System.import("/js/app");
                });
        });
</script>
```

**App.js**

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap,  OnInit} from 'angular2';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'winjs';
import '../js/content'

@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard-app'
})
@View({
    templateUrl: '../js/dashboard.html'
})
class MyAppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
    }

    onInit() {
        WinJS.UI.processAll().done(function () {
            var splitView = document.querySelector(".splitView").winControl;
            new WinJS.UI._WinKeyboard(splitView.paneElement); // Temporary workaround: Draw keyboard focus visuals on NavBarCommands
        });
    }
}

bootstrap(MyAppComponent);
```

**content.js**

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap,  OnInit} from 'angular2';
import 'reflect-metadata';

@Component({
    selector: 'contentarea'
})
@View({
    template: '<h3>Testing</h3>'
})
class ContentComponent {
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

**dashboard.html**

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="splitView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitView" data-win-options="{ openedDisplayMode : 'inline' }">
        <div>
            <div class="header">
                <button class="win-splitviewpanetoggle"
                        data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitViewPaneToggle"
                        data-win-options="{ splitView: select('.splitView') }">
                </button>
                <div class="title">SplitView Pane area</div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-commands">
                <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand" data-win-options="{ label: 'Home', icon: 'home'}"></div>
                <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand" data-win-options="{ label: 'Favorite', icon: 'favorite'}"></div>
                <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand" data-win-options="{ label: 'Settings', icon: 'settings'}"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contenttext">
            <contentarea></contentarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding **directives** like below fixed it:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard-app'
})
@View({
    templateUrl: '../js/dashboard.html'
    directives: [ ContentComponent ]
})
```